# should I use na.omit or na.exclude in a linear model (in R)?

Tags: r, regression, linear-model, residuals, missing-data

I try to understand the difference between using different na.actions (na.omit and na.exclude) to handle missing data in a linear model using R. I used the lm function in R (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/lm.html).

The summary of my linear model prints exactly the same for na.omit and na.exclude. But if I look at the residuals, the na.exclude gives me NA' s for the cases where there was an NA and it gives me a list of residuals without NA for the na.omit.

```
residuals.lm(lm_1_exclude)

 1       2       3       4    5       6       7       8            
-0.0526 -0.0930 -0.3295  NA  -0.1520 -0.3217 -0.3220  0.0722  

residuals.lm(lm_1_omit)

 1       2       3            5       6       7      8            
-0.0526 -0.0930 -0.3295      -0.1520 -0.3217 -0.3220  0.0722
```

I now would like to understand, which option should be preferred in a linear model and how this affects my statistics.. unfortunately, I only could find tutorials explaining that these different options exist, but no advice on what to choose. https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-does-r-handle-missing-values/

Comment: Based on [this](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-does-r-handle-missing-values/#:~:text=omit%20and%20na.,pass%3A%20returns%20the%20object%20unchanged) link, it appears that from estimation point of view both are equivalent as they remove the row where any of the dependent or independent variable is missing. Only benefit of `na.exclude` is that it retains the position where data was missing in the final residual vector. If that is something you want then that makes `na.exclude` preferable over `na.omit`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The only benefit of `na.exclude` over `na.omit` is that the former will retain the original number of rows in the data. This may be useful where you need to retain the original size of the dataset - for example it is useful when you want to compare predicted values to original values. With `na.omit` you will end up with fewer rows so you won't as easily be able to compare.

Comment: Does this apply to other linear models i.e. linear mixed effects model.,  lme function?